# How to stop React Webpack from including scripts from package.json

Tags: reactjs, security, webpack, version, package.json

I recently stumbled on what looks like a security issue to me. When I had a look at the `main.[...].js` file being deployed to my website, I noticed that it included my entire package.json file, which has some scripts I'd rather not have exposed to the world.

This is probably happening because I'm importing the file in order to get the current deployment version and log it with any bug reports. How can I go about getting that version from the package.json file without actually importing the file and exposing it?

Even if I import just the `{ version }` and not the entire file, Webpack still packages the whole thing (which makes me wonder what the point of that even is?).

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Which webpack version are you using? This should work in 4.x https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/5578

Comment: I've been using create-react-app and it seems they're on version 3.8.1. Does that mean I need to eject and start managing all of this stuff myself to get to the latest version of Webpack?

Comment: Yes, I think you would need to eject to change the webpack version.

Comment: Okay, thanks! I'm going to wait a few weeks (my website isn't live yet) to see if they upgrade before then, and if not, I'll eject it. Please post your comment as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tree shaking for json files like you need it is a new feature in webpack 4.x
Here is the ticket:
https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/5578

You could write a script to read the version number and write it into its own file before webpack runs and import this one if you have to stay on 3.x, but hopefully create-react-app will update soon. There is already an open pull request here:
https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/4077